# How to use fopen in C

Tags: c, fopen

I have problems using fopen() in c.

When I compile and run this:

```
const char* mode="r";
FILE* imgstream = fopen(pathinput, mode);
```

I am getting a Segmentation fault:

```
main called
argv[1]: /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm
open mode: r
./testscript: line 6: 12454 Segmentation fault      ./flippr /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm /home/student/workspace/Flip/test_out.pbm
```

It appears to me that it should be working ...
What am I doing wrong?

the whole code of main.c :

```
#include "flip.h"
#include "img.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pbm_image_flip(PbmImage* image){
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("main called\n");
#endif
    int* error=RET_PBM_OK;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);
#endif

    const char* mode="r";
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("open mode: %s\n", mode);
#endif
    FILE* imgstream = fopen(argv[1], mode);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("imgstream fopen");
#endif
    PbmImage* pbmimage=pbm_image_load_from_stream(imgstream, error);

    pbm_image_flip(pbmimage);

    return 0;
}
```

The code runs until before I try to fopen the stream.

Comment: `'r'` is a character literal. You want a string literal, `"r"`.

Comment: oh, thanks, but I am still getting a segmentation fault:
main called
pathlen: 41
pathinput: /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm
open mode: r
./testscript: line 6: 12214 Segmentation fault      ./flippr /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm /home/student/workspace/Flip/test_out.pbm

Comment: And you expect us to check out your code in our crystal balls and debug it for you? For free?

Comment: No, but i thought I might have some other obvious syntax errors in my code that I wasnt able to find. I updated the question now with the whole code.

Answer (score 4):

The error comes from this line:

```
const char* mode='r';
```

There is a difference between singe and double quotes in C. Single are for characters, double for string literals (which can be safely assigned to `char*`)

The solution for you would be

```
FILE* imgstream = fopen(pathinput,"r");
```

Comment: Ok, now I got rid of the warnings, but the segmentation fault is still there

main called
pathlen: 41
pathinput: /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm
open mode: r
./testscript: line 6: 12214 Segmentation fault      ./flippr /home/student/workspace/Flip/res/test.pbm /home/student/workspace/Flip/test_out.pbm

Comment: How do you declare/populate `pathinput`? post your code!

Comment: Your problem is `char pathinput[pathlen];` `strlen` returns the length of the string, to store it you need one byte more for the null terminator. To be honest I am puzzled why you copy it at all. What is wrong with `fopen(argv[1],"r");`? Just make sure that argument was actually supplied.

Answer (score 1):

There is still one problem:

```
int* error = RET_PBM_OK;
```

will crash or will lead to a crash later. You are using an uninitialized pointer.

Write this:

```
int error = RET_PBM_OK ;
...
PbmImage* pbmimage=pbm_image_load_from_stream(imgstream, &error);
```

But this is bad practice. Normally `pbm_image_load_from_stream` shoud take care of setting error to RET_PBM_OK if it succeeds. In that case you don't even need to initialize `error` before calling `pbm_image_load_from_stream`.